# .NET MVC 3 Routes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Recently I've made the transition from Web Forms to MVC 3 and I've been trying to get to grips with MVC routes. I have a somewhat peculiar problem in that when I receive a request to my application (e.g. subdomain1.organisation.com or subdomain2.organisation.com) I wish the default route to be used as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

However, when a request is received by my application through a particular subdomain e.g. subdomain3.organisation.com, I want the application to default to a particular controller. I've been following code at:

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx

which should what I want. So the code in my Global.asax is as follows:

```
routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute(
    "subdomain3.organisation.com", // Domain with parameters
    "{action}/{id}",    // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Subdomain3Controller", action = "Index", id = "" }
));

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When deployed, my application behaves correctly when requests are sent to subdomain3.organisation.com, using Subdomain3Controller. However, when visiting any other subdomain e.g. localhost/Subdomain3Controller/Index my application seems to select the incorrect route.

My form helpers appear to return an incorrect value for:

```
ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").AttemptedValue

@using(Html.BeginForm(ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").AttemptedValue, ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").AttemptedValue, FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object> {{ "id", "formid" } })){
```

Any ideas why this might be? Any light that anyone could shed on this issue would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [routing debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx), which is designed to help debug these sorts of problems

Looks like it's installable via Nuget now too.

Comment: Thanks for this - that's a very useful tool which I have used to confirm that the route I expected to be using is in fact being used i.e. route 2 in the above. However, I still having no idea why my BeginForm helper is returning the incorrect controller.

Answer (score 0):

I've also noticed that if I hard-code the controller name into the BeginForm helper, the incorrect action value is still returned:

```
      using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Subdomain3Controller", FormMethod.Post, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "formid" } }))
        {
```

generates:

```
<form id="formid" method="post" action="/">
```

rather than:

```
 <form id="formid" method="post" action="/Subdomain3Controller">
```

when viewing:

http://localhost/Subdomain3Controller/ or http://localhost/Subdomain3Controller/Index

Comment: Oddly, I've also noticed that BeginForm() actually will return the correct path - it's only this overload which seems to be an issue.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's worth observing that the values generated by BeginForm might well be correct if you were accessing the site via subdomain3.organisation.com however totally incorrect when viewing:

http://localhost/Subdomain3Controller/ or http://localhost/Subdomain3Controller/Index

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled on a similar problem and managed to find a solution for this problem. I'm aware this might not help the original author, but it might help some other people who end up here via search.

Anyway, it seems the route name "Default" doesn't add much weight. When BeginForm is constructing its URL it takes the first route from the route collection that 'fits'. I didn't dig too deep into how this all works internally.

What I did to solve this problem was add a constraint to the subdomain route so it can only be used for the Subdomain3Controller, as such:

```
        var domainRoute =  new DomainRoute(
            "subdomain3.organisation.com", // Domain with parameters
            "{action}/{id}",    // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Subdomain3Controller", action = "Index", id = "" }
        );

        domainRoute.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary();
        webserviceRoute.Constraints.Add("Controller", "Subdomain3Controller");

        routes.Add("DomainRoute", domainRoute);
```

[edit]
After thinking about this a little bit more and realizing my situation was a bit different from the situation of the original poster. The above won't work, because the controller is not inside of the URL anymore.

A solution might be to switch the order of the routes, and add a NotEqual constraint for the subdomains to the default route. As described in http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2008/08/07/asp-net-mvc-tip-30-create-custom-route-constraints.aspx
[/edit]